# How can I give git access to my OpenShift repository?

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

The terminal output says it all:

```
git push --repo origin
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in

<deprecation warnings>

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have...

- made sure that it is the correct repository URL
- `git add`'ed and `git commit`'ed

However, I haven't...

- logged in to OpenShift on Git
- given git a ssh (I don't know how and I don't know how to get a SSH either)

I am using

- Git 1.8.4
- OpenShift free

Is it because...

- I need a SSH? (**likely the culprit**)
- I need to log in? (From a coder's  perspective, probably not.)
- I have the wrong URL? (It was auto-configured)

Also, does SSH **require** a secure connection? It sounds like a dumb question, but I can't use secure connections, and I don't care *too* much if the connection isn't secure. Git seems to allow connecting without a secure connection.

Comment: What does "I can't use secure connections" mean?

Comment: It means no SSL. At all.

Comment: Your free plan not supporting outgoing SSL has nothing whatsoever to do with SSH. SSH and SSL are *entirely* separate. When you connect over SSH, SSH does its own encryption, without using SSL. It's not clear what language you are working with, but looking at the [Python Getting Started page](https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-getting-started.html) it seems clear that OpenShift does support Git over SSH, so you're good to go there. I'm still not sure what you're asking...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't setup ssh keys for your Openshift app.

See "[Remote Connection (SSH)](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html)", which explains in details how to generate and setup ssh keys.